# At least one of $ax+bc > 0$, $xy+cz > 0$, $yd+zt > 0$ or $da+tb>0$ is false

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ and $x,y,z,t < 0$ real numbers. Prove that at least one of the inequalities $ax+bc > 0$, $xy+cz > 0$, $yd+zt > 0$ or $da+tb>0$ is false.

I assume by contradiction they are all true, but what to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty geometric interpretation of these inequalities. In a system of coordinates $xOy$, the points $A(a,b),\ B(x,c),\ C(y,z)$ and $D(d,z)$ lie in the four quadrants I, II, III and IV, respectively.

At least one of the angles $\angle AOB, \angle BOC, \angle COD$ or $\angle DOA$ is greater than or equal to $90^\circ$. Let's say that angle is $\angle AOB$. Then the dot product of the vectors $\overrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overrightarrow{OB}$ is smaller than or equal to $0$, that is

$$ax+bc \leq 0$$

Comment: Nice observation (+1).  Have you seen this sort of problem before?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I used to enjoy studying lattices back in high school :)

Comment: Never even crossed my mind to look for a geometric picture here.  It will next time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assume all four are true.

Write them as $$|bc|>|ax|\quad \quad  |xy|>|cz|\quad \quad  |zt|>|yd|\quad \quad  |ad|>|tb|$$

From the first and  fourth we deduce that $$|abcd|>|axtb|\implies |cd|>|xt|$$

From the second and  third we deduce that $$|xyzt|>|czyd|\implies |xt|>|cd|$$
and we have a contradiction.